# Align two image buttons horizontally in landscape layout Android with a text view under each one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am making a chooser screen e.g gallery or take photo. I have made the portrait layout ok but struggling with landscape. I am trying to use DroidDraw. This is the kind of look I am going for as a sample (ignore the buttons), but the layout is deprecated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <AbsoluteLayout
  android:id="@+id/widget65"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
android:id="@+id/widget66"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="CAMERA"
android:layout_x="136dp"
android:layout_y="96dp" />
    <Button
android:id="@+id/widget67"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="GALLERY"
android:layout_x="272dp"
android:layout_y="95dp" />
    <TextView
android:id="@+id/widget68"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Choose from Gallery"
android:layout_x="246dp"
android:layout_y="146dp" />
    <TextView
android:id="@+id/widget69"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Take Picture"
android:layout_x="117dp"
android:layout_y="149dp" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Throw away AbsoluteLayout.   Really, don't use it.  Check out Relativelayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget65"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/widget66"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="CAMERA" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widget68"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Choose from Gallery" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/widget67"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="GALLERY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widget69"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Take Picture" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly. I am now trying to add a text view to the top of a layout for a title, but not sure how to include in the linear layout without making the rest of the alignment out of whack.